# How to create an instance of tagged union given I have key and value for it

Tags: typescript, generics, unions

I want to create a function that takes a generic argument - key of tagged union - and value - value of said union - and create an instance of this union. Here is an example

```
type TagA = 'x' | 'y' | 'z';
type TagB = 'm' | 'n';

type UnionExampleA = 
    | { tag: 'x', value: number}
    | { tag: 'y', value: [number, number]}
    | { tag: 'z', value: string}

type UnionExampleB = 
    | { tag: 'm', value: string}
    | { tag: 'n', value: null}

type UnionKey<T> = T extends { tag: infer R} ? R : never; 
type UnionValue<T> = T extends { value: infer R} ? R : never; 

function foo<UnionType>(tag: UnionKey<UnionType>, value: UnionValue<UnionType>): UnionType {
    return {
        tag,
        value
    }
}

const a = foo<UnionExampleA>('y', [15, 25]);
const b = foo<UnionExampleB>('m', '25');

// should not compile
// const c = foo<UnionExampleB>('y', [15, 25]);
```

So we have some sample types and calling example. So we want to pass `y` as key and `[15, 25]` as value and get `{'y': [15, 25]}` instance of `UnionExampleA` type. Same for `UnionExampleB` in second case.

Comment: I'm confused by this question.  You say "how do I [constrain] `Tag` to be a tag in [a] tagged union and `ValType` to be a corresponding value in said union"?  But I don't see `Tag` or `ValType` anywhere else in your question; what are they?  Where do you want to constrain things?  Does the example code demonstrate the problem you're having?  If so, where?  Is it the compile error in the function body?   Help!

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I was changing my question continuously until it no longer was valid. I updated my question to be correct now. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't know what your problem is.   Does the example code demonstrate the problem you're having? If so, where? Is it the compile error in the function body?

Comment: Yes, this snipped doesn't currently compile because compiler do not allow me to construct unknown `UnionType` using only two fields and I cannot convince him I do not have other fields and these are of correct type.

Comment: Okay, then could you please [edit] the question so that it's very clear what the issue is?  Given your current code I would recommend just using a type assertion like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w1AQkw).  But if you really care about type safety verified by the compiler you'll probably need to refactor to something frankly much more complicated and confusing, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJ7rrw).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Type assertion for sure isn't the right call but your last link looks like it is what I'd actually like to have. I would be happy to mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler can't follow your logic; technically it would be possible for the type argument to have more properties than just `tag` and `value`, so it's unsafe to return `{tag, value}` anyway.

If you want to write something the compiler *can* follow, and also keep it so that the function is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in only a single type parameter which you intend to manually instantiate when you call the function, then the following is the best I can do:

```
type Mapping<U extends { tag: string, value: any }> =
    { [T in U as T['tag']]: T["value"] };

type TagValueToTuple<U extends { tag: string, value: any }> =
    { [P in keyof Mapping<U>]: [tag: P, value: Mapping<U>[P]] }[keyof Mapping<U>];

type PickTagValue<U extends { tag: string, value: any }> =
    { [P in keyof Mapping<U>]: { tag: P, value: Mapping<U>[P] } }[keyof Mapping<U>];

function foo<U extends { tag: string, value: any }>(
    ...[tag, value]: TagValueToTuple<U>
): PickTagValue<U> {
    return { tag, value };
}
```

So `foo` is still generic in one type parameter `U` representing the full [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), which I have [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to a type with a `string`-assignable `tag` property and some `value` property.

Then, it accepts a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) of type `TagValueToTuple<U>`, which is [destructured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) into `tag` and `value` parameters.  The `TagValueToTuple<U>` type takes the [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) `U` corresponding to the intended output, and turns it into a discriminated union of [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types).  For example:

```
type TupleExampleA = TagValueToTuple<UnionExampleA>
// type TupleExampleA = 
//  [tag: "x", value: number] | 
//  [tag: "y", value: [number, number]] | 
//  [tag: "z", value: string]
```

And it returns a value of type `PickTagValue<U>`, which is another union similar to `U` except that it has only the `tag` and `value` properties.  For example:

```
type PickExampleB = PickTagValue<UnionExampleB>;
// type PickExampleB = 
//   { tag: "m"; value: string; } | 
//   { tag: "n"; value: null; }
```

The reason why both `TagValueToTuple<U>` and `PickTagValue<U>` are written the way they are, in terms of `Mapping<U>`, is to make them both *distributive object types* as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  This is specifically a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) into which one immediately [indexes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to get a union.  And, as per microsoft/TypeScript#47109, the compiler is able to understand the correlation between types in this way.

If you tried rewriting the types to equivalent versions but did not use distributive object types, the implementation would have errors:

```
type TagValueToTuple2<U extends { tag: string, value: any }> =
    U extends { tag: infer T, value: infer V } ? [tag: T, value: V] : never;
type PickTagValue2<U extends { tag: string, value: any }> =
    U extends unknown ? Pick<U, "tag" | "value"> : never;
function foo2<U extends { tag: string, value: any }>(
    ...[tag, value]: TagValueToTuple2<U>
): PickTagValue2<U> {
    return { tag, value }; // error!
}
```

---

Anyway, let's make sure it still works when you call it:

```
const a: UnionExampleA = foo<UnionExampleA>('y', [15, 25]);
const b: UnionExampleB = foo<UnionExampleB>('m', '25');    
const c = foo<UnionExampleB>('y', [15, 25]); // error!
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgcwIJQLxQOQA8NQD6Yi4EYBeGA3AFCiSyIBCamAtsZgHaVU3jQCqHAJYB7DgFEscFmAA2EFKipQV+KAG8owRAC5MOADRQAbnFkBXCHo7mWAIwgAnKAF9lqgpu0I9GIkdMLKygAbRt7JyNwh0cAXVd3FU8tXUxyALNLPQBnYEchDgQE3jpBUQkpGXkmJVU1L1SMNgygnLyCorc65O9fLhasqBtZWWKS6ABZODAwDoAefigILGAIDgATbI0Unyhc-MKB4LgOEFcAPjRE7ZCYKAKoRbgtmBCMbwxY2L1XgCJAyy-eIuajjegIABqmQgMBEMHMcggCyWKzWm22vT27UOJmhehOZxcl1qqk0IQACvcOFAANYQEAiABmUCmM3m-HO31CmPJRz0rNmhQW5wpX1cITpDOZAvZnNBtGg5KEAGMafBIdDkctVhstg1dvsOnyoASLlc6mTKQ9JUyWdNBQhhVz9XpebjWna2UKOaLXOKbdL7bLYqDGeYOMrgOUoIyRCItajdRjUoacQDjqcLgAKa4AOnzIW8Ry56qhQVh8MRwqoAEpXSq1Ygy5ZhRpro4IMBzI5qfqjq5qG4waXoRWEfIAEwJnXol1Yg4IY2monm1SLbVovU7PQFRlOWDG3f7iF+gD83NSMGNEPi1ggxic1AVUCVqpHQSn68Ts+386N7sGZdiWuL8Zy2cMaQ4EQAHdqXPV8aQWIxfm8X41H+aFfkuO8H0cagwwjKMxBjONPxRMDkwNbFFwAjNCXOHM6nzXNC0QYsfibUc4XHCBP3OWt6zfTiP1bdR207btex2fsQSgAB6OSlkcRwREcABCKgh2HHjJGkRFFHBZsYW4qsyjEXSqgUfiFK0PhYB0yp9OYKgbIvXZfiwX5jWiJx4gIFzFLcvRfhALzaL0MJbBiKIot8vyoAClRWPc0gwvTNoF1iHhnwQizERqF8G3fFszIqPTqnOagbJyhs8uqZzXMo4KWF+Chwr-Qo2pcNREpUOdfg4Vr2uGWQup4ZUxFyE09FKuqFGYWN41mxz5CQBi-AwIwQgARgAViMCddtiGtqAmjgprsGbhHMlaIAKxaFmusrLIYdbmkwQ6MBOqgzqm5UFrjR7yjm16sw2ra9oOo6TqAA)